# NetBeans IDE: Resolve Missing Native Build Tools

Tags: netbeans, fortran, mingw, gfortran, fortran90

I am trying to install Fortran in my Windows 10 laptop.

I followed step-by-step [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGv2kGl8OV0) tutorial.

On the last step I am promted to run the following piece of code:

```
program testfortran
    implicit none
    print*,'Hello world '
end program testfortran
```

However a `Resolve Missing Native Build Tools` window pops-up: it seems that the `Make command` field is empty.

To be more specific at the bottom of this window there is a message that `Tolls marked with * are required`. There are three such fields:

(1)`C++ compiler` to which is attributed the message `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`

(2)`Fortran compiler` to which is attributed the message `C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe`

(3) `Make command` which is empty (it comes with a red *)

What should I write inside the `Make command` field?

P.S. All I want is Fortran 90/95 installed on my Windows 10 laptop. I try to do this with step-by-step tutorials because installing software is not exactly what I am good at. So any alternatives would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW comes with the `mingw32-make` program (or it can be installed by `mingw-get install mingw32-make`). So you should use

```
C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe
```